# How to "scan" across the channels?

Tags: slack-api

I hope you can guide me on which API to use.
I need to develop a bot or script with the Slack API, which:

- Listen to all public channels in my workspace.
- Detects messages when a specific word is mentioned.

So, I went to https://api.slack.com/, but I couldn't identify which API resource I should use.
Please, which API feature detects words on all public channels in my workspace? Thank you

Comment: Look here: https://api.slack.com/bot-users

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is look at Slack Events [API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). Using this API you will be able to subscribe to events in your workspace, which in this case is [`message`](https://api.slack.com/events/message). Note if you are using the Bot token ensure you add your slack app to all the channels you wish to receive `message` event notifications from.